# A simple free auto typer program that stays always on top of other windows

Tags: windows, gratis, automation

At my job for a company's website, I need to input some information about an order and for multiple orders. Unfortunately, for this site, for some reason, pasting information results in it being duplicated. It's a form that uses java and is hosted online. Maybe we can email the company and maybe it will be fixed, but in the meanwhile, I would like to come up with a workaround.

So, if I paste 567, what gets pasted is 567567. I must then delete the second 567. Or instead, I must type the numbers. The numbers are very long and both options are annoying.

**Software Requirements:**

I would like to find a simple free auto typer program. One which stays up on top of other windows, and has a text box / field where I can paste the numbers, and then click on that field whenever I want to paste what's in it and optionally / maybe or use a keyboard shortcut (not sure how convenient the keyboard shortcut would be considering I need to use the mouse to hop around different fields and tabs). I want to then easily and quickly be able to paste new numbers in the program, replacing the existing ones, and then click on the numbers whenever I want to paste them. Replacing the text should be as easy as highlighting the previous numbers or doing Ctrl + A, and then pasting the new numbers.

If it could support multiple fields, that might also be great, because there is another area where I always need to type an address, which is split across multiple fields (address, city, state, zip). I don't know if pasting works there, but considering it doesn't work anwywhere else, I doubt it will there.

Auto Typer by Murgee.com comes close, but it's too many clicks to edit an existing entry and the program doesn't stay visible on top of others.

Comment: What about making a quick Userscript for that ?

Comment: You should also state whether its OK for the information to leave your security boundary (i.e., the local computer). Also see [The Best Dictation (Voice To Text) Software Is Here (And It’s Free!)](http://www.minterest.org/best-dictation-software/) and [Dictation Programs for Windows and Mac](http://www.nch.com.au/software/dictation.html). [The Beginner's Guide to Dictation Software: Write Without Typing](https://zapier.com/blog/best-text-dictation-software/) is also a good article.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like some of the fields could be efficiently filled using speech recognition with [Dragon NaturallySpeaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/transcription-solutions/index.htm) (Windows / OS X, not gratis) or [Mac Dictation](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5449) (OS X, gratis, built-in and usable since 10.10): you can define most voice commands that simulate typing strings. E.g. when I say:

- "my zipcode" it writes "02139"
- "my phone number" it writes "+1-449-231-6988"
- "my email address" it writes "franck.dernonnospamcourt@gmail.com"
- etc.

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. I am looking for a non-speaking approach. I am also looking for free software.

Comment: Dragon does not perform well in the overall picture. They start by surreptitiously [installing insecure malware](http://superuser.com/q/1096940) that immediately starts serving ads. Others claimed its an updater, but there were no updates after the install (imagine that... a six month or year old DVD that did not need one update). I recommend avoiding Dragon. I'm taking my purchase back tomorrow (and looking for an alternative).

Comment: @jww yes the issue is finding an alternative for speech recognition. Have fun with Ramhound...

Comment: Thanks. Ramhound is a piece of work. He's finally pushed me over the edge...

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you asked for, but it has the capability to achieve what you need: [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/). It is potentially even better than what you were looking for, because you said you have to "hop around different fields and tabs", and this can be automated with AutoHotkey.

If you have some programming ability, you could even build your own application with AutoHotkey which reads all the various pieces of data you want to copy and "types" them into all the fields you need to fill.

Answer (score 0):

> A simple free auto typer program that stays always on top of other windows...

Your question is tagged [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), but I'm going to offer something that includes Linux and Unix. This may be viable for those who run Linux, or those who are comfortable with a Linux VM on Windows.

I've done a fair amount of research because the canonical answer seems to be *"Dragon Naturally Speaking"*. I found Dragon to be most disagreeable, especially when it [surreptitiously installed adware that hid in `C:\ProgramData`](https://superuser.com/q/1096940/173513). In my case, I performed a custom install, and I clearly was not asked about installing adware. I also found Dragon's dependence on Adobe warez troubling because Adobe is renowned for its insecure software.

Here are some alternatives from the Linux and Unix world. They are based on [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/). The list was taken from their [Projects using Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/sphinxinaction) page:

- Jasper: Personal assistant for Raspberry Pi
- Gnome-Voice-Control: Gnome-Voice-Control is a dialogue system to control the GNOME Desktop
- Perlbox: Provides voice solutions for Linux and Unix desktop control
- Mammoth: Becoming a full blown high concurrency C++ Flash Streaming Server running on windows and *nix. Uses pocketsphinx for speech recognition
- Twitterkiller: TWiT podcast improver, filters advertising
- Arabisc: Arabic acoustic model.
- Voicekey: voice-controlled keyboard for GNU/Linux.
- SpeechLion: Desktop control application using Sphinx4 and FreeTTS written in python.
- Nightingale: Voice Web Browser
- Misterhouse: an open source home automation program.
- Vedics: Yet another command-and-control specifically for guys from India! Only check if you are Indian from the Punjab!
- PocketVox: Pocketsphinx-based voice control for GNOME
- ILA voice assistant: ILA voice assistant

Other well known engines include:

- Google Docs: Voice Typing
- OS X: Dictation
- Windows: Speech Recognition